# How to silent ‘Attempting a database schema change is discouraged.’?

Tags: plugin-development

I have inherited one plugin for WordPress to develop. I use [WordPress-Coding-Standards](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards) to make the code more coherent. It is a lost case, but the client knows better. The validation tool points me to a warning below:

> Attempting a database schema change is discouraged.

The code looks like this:

```
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query(
            '
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'rest_of_name
                (table definition);
            '
        ); /* db call ok; no cache ok */
```

I need to silent the warning about schema update too.

Comment: what are the lines of code that are triggering this? Is the plugin trying to modify columns on WP Core tables? Is this a custom plugin or something from .org/3rd party?

Comment: It is a custom plugin. It try to create a new table. (I edited question a little.)

Comment: have you looked into the `dbDelta` function?

Comment: The function dbDelta is nod defined in a context I work in. I cannot change it without the code refactoring.

Comment: that's extremely unusual/unlikely, every example for `dbDelta` in the docs includes a `require_once` statement to load it into the current context, _are you absolutely sure you checked the official `dbDelta` documentation thoroughly?_ see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank You. I thought I cannot include that file with `dbDelta` by myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the **Schema Change** along with **Direct Quer**y and **No Caching** warnings in these two ways-

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}rest_of_the_name" ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.NoCaching, WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery, WordPress.DB.DirectDatabaseQuery.SchemaChange
```

or

```
global $wpdb;
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
$wpdb->query( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}rest_of_the_name" );
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```